# Prisoner Question, Similar to Monty Hall problem I think

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Here's the question

Three prisoners, A, B, and C, are locked in their cells. It is common knowledge that one of them is to be executed the next day and the others are to be pardoned. Only the Governor knows which one will be executed. Prisoner A asks the guard a favor: "Please ask the Governor who will be executed, and then take a message to one of my friends B or C to let him know that he will be pardoned in the morning." The Guard agrees, and comes back later and tells A that he gave the pardon message to B. What are A's chances of being executed, given this information?

I need to show the solution mathematically.  I don't see how this question is any different than the Monty Hall problem [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

With that as my base I come to the conclusion that Prisoner A has a 1/3 chance of being executed.  And that prisoner C would then have a 2/3 chance.  Is that correct?  If so how do I show it mathematically?

Edit: Mathematical solution

[image: tree]

The only options for B being pardoned are circled.  Resulting probability:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}.1} =\frac{1}{3}$$

[click to view calculations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F3+*+1%2F2%29+%2F+%28%281%2F3+*+1%2F2%29+%2B+%281%2F3+*+1%29%29)

Comment: I would agree this is the same as the monty hall problem

Comment: Have you tried any of the methods by which people have solved the Monty Hall problem? What happened then?

Comment: I think I found the solution, could you read what I added to the original post and confirm?

Comment: Since there are three people and only one is to be executed the probability that A gets executed is 1/3.  Asking the question makes no difference to A's chances. The guard knows who is being executed so the possibility of one of B or C being executed is 2/3 and when the guard tells B he is to be pardoned then C has a 2/3 probability of being executed.

Comment: The two "paradoxes" have different angles. The Monty Hall questions if changing the choice changes the probability (it does indeed). The Prisoner questions if receiving a seemingly useless piece of information changes the probability (it does not, provided that the Guard passes the message with equal probabilities when the other prisoners are in identical situations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution while searching through the monty hall problem wikipedia page.  They make a tree.  So here it is.  I've also updated the original post with this answer.

Mathematical solution

[image: tree]

The only options for B being pardoned are circled.  Resulting probability
$$P =\frac{ \frac{1}{3} \times\frac{ 1}{2}}{ \left(\frac{1}{3} \times\frac{ 1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3} \times 1\right)} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

[click to view calculations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F3+*+1%2F2%29+%2F+%28%281%2F3+*+1%2F2%29+%2B+%281%2F3+*+1%29%29)